# Meraki REST API - Missing endpoints?

Tags: meraki-api

we have a problem with Cisco Meraki REST API (https://developer.cisco.com/meraki/api/#/rest/)
It seems that there doesn't exist REST endpoints for getting such basic information like ARP, MAC tables.

Is there anyone who knows how to get this data per device?

Answer (score 0):

I think that is the older site for the API. The one I use is at https://dashboard.meraki.com/api_docs and it contains a lot more options. I don't know if ARP and Mac Address Tables are available anywhere, but there is a developer early access program that you can join to get a look at the upcoming version 1 :https://developer.cisco.com/meraki/meraki-developer-early-access-program/.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your suggestion to join early access program.